# Why are there no sub folders under drawables folder in Android studio as of the latest updates?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable

Like in recent versions we used to find drawables-ldpi, drawables--mdpi etc but these don't exist now. Should i create those or just copy them in the drawables folder without these sub folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a drawable folder for the DPI that you need, you can create it yourself. There's nothing magical about it; it's just a folder which needs to have the correct name. for example **drawable-hdpi** ,**drawable-xhdpi**,**drawable-xxdpi**,**drawable-xxxdpi** etc.

Answer (score 0):

u can just paste your file or anything no need of hdpi and mdpi folder in drawable.